# I want to POST variables from actionscript 3.0 to PHP

Tags: php, actionscript-3

I am trying to send some variables from my actionscript 3.0 to PHP file..
but if i am using POST method I am getting an error instead if I use GET method it is working fine but then there comes the security issue.
All my variables are displayed in URL which I dont want to happen.
This is my code:

```
gbtn.addEventListener(MouseEvent.CLICK,btng);

function btng(event:MouseEvent):void{
    var myVariables:URLVariables = new URLVariables();

     myVariables.white = "white";

     var myURLRequest:URLRequest = new URLRequest("scene4.php");

     myURLRequest.data = myVariables;

     navigateToURL(myURLRequest, '_self');

     gotoAndPlay(1,"Scene 4");
}
```

Please help.
thanx...:)

Comment: `POST` isnt going to make anything secure - firebug or any built in debugger can display the `POST` data. So it might not be visible for everyone but its certainly not secure

Comment: hmmmm
actually i am doing a very basic kind of project and i just want my URL to be clean.
Can you please suggest some secure method..

Comment: I agree with ManseUK. Basicly those you want to hide this from are those who can find out the POST value regardless. The rest who doesn't see it have no intend to use the data either. I'd consider some kind of validation instead.

Answer (score 1):

```
var scriptRequest:URLRequest = new URLRequest("scene4.php");
var scriptLoader:URLLoader = new URLLoader();
var scriptVars:URLVariables = new URLVariables(); 
scriptVars.white = "white"; 
scriptRequest.method = URLRequestMethod.POST;
scriptRequest.data = scriptVars; 
scriptLoader.load(scriptRequest);
```

Comment: You didn't make it work, cause it works :) Check this out : http://blog.turtlebite.com/send-and-load-variables-with-as3-and-php/  (that VarLoader class it neat, i always use it)

Comment: Eric your method didn't worked out..
In PHP page using POST method i am getting an error as "undefined index: white"

Comment: What's your php script like ?

Comment: I got some other solution and it worked perfectly fine...:)
Anyways Thanx for the help..:)